# Decode json With PHP not working

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode json with PHP but dont know where am i wrong. Here is my code

```
$rr ='var modelsGlobal = [{"value":"FAFW3801LW","productdetailurl":"/Washers-Dryers/Washers/Front-Load/FAFW3801LW/"}{"value":"FAFW3801LW","productdetailurl":"/Washers-Dryers/Washers/Front-Load/FAFW3801LW/"}]';

$json = json_decode($rr, true);
        foreach($json['modelsGlobal'] as $json){
        $prod_id = $json["value"];
        }
```

Please help

Comment: may be, because it's not json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to decode (broken) **JavaScript**, not JSON.

JSON wouldn't include `var modelsGlobal =` and array members need a `,` between them.

Run your data through [a linter](http://jsonlint.com/).

---

After you fix the errors which are preventing the parsing, the JSON doesn't start with an object with a `modelsGlobal`, so loop over the array in `$json` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect. It is not JSON but JavaScript and it lacks a comma to separate the two objects of the array.

If you use PHP 5.3+ use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to check errors with json_encode/json_decode.